# PHP - Telegram Bot interactive query

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm trying to query some data from my database. there is three option for searching data from database

1. User id
2. Phone no.
3. E-mail

I've created an inline keyboard by choosing a search option from the above list
[Screenshot of bot chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPZlV.png)

**I'm looking for a solution** where if I choose user_id then the bot will ask me to insert user_id. And will accept the only user_id as input. otherwise, it will return with an error message.

if I choose email from the inline keyboard at that time bot will accept only email that time. other bot commands will not be accepted until any error or success is returned from the bot.

**I'm using Laravel as my backend.**

Comment: How can we get input from user and save in database? I want to get some information from user one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a column called `state` for each `user_id`.
And when you receive any message you should check the `state` before responding.

So, This is pseudo-code:

```php
$Bot = new TelegramBot(getenv('BOT_TOKEN'));

function MessageHandler($message)
{
    $state = DB::table('users')->row(['user_id' => $message->from->id])->column('state');

    if ($state === false)
    {
        # Create new row for this user..
    }

    switch ($state)
    {
        case 'SEARCHING_BY_ID':
            # Check if message is number
            break;

        case 'SEARCHING_BY_PHONE':
            # Check if message is phone number
            break;


        case 'SEARCHING_BY_MAIL':
            # Check if message is E-mail
            break;

        default:
            # Now you should process by any command
            break;
    }
}

$Bot->OnMessage(MessageHandler);
```